# Not work UITableView in cellForRowAt But numberOfRowsInsection Work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wrote a function to add a Cell in a `UITableView`.

`numberOfRowsInSection` works but `cellForRowAt` does not work.

```
class ShopMenuViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!

    var menuPrice: MenuPrice!

    override func awakeFromNib() 
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}

extension ShopMenuViewCell
{
    func setView()
    {
        self.menuTableView.delegate = self
        self.menuTableView.dataSource = self
        self.menuTableView.regCells(cells: ["ShopMenuInformationCell"])

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.menuTableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}

extension ShopMenuViewCell : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShopMenuInformationCell", for: indexPath) as? ShopMenuInformationCell,
            let menu = self.menuPrice,
            let name = menu.name,
            let price = menu.amt else { return ShopMenuInformationCell() }

        return cell
    }
}
```

In ShpMenuInformationCell.swift

```
class ShopMenuInformationCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

I saw the answer to add a `ViewController`, but I do not know what to do because it is not a storyboard. (.xib)

I think it is because I add `UITableViewCell` in the `UITableViewCell` class.

Do you know why?

Comment: Please add `regCells` function code.

Comment: I did not understand your request.

Comment: tableview is inside another tableview cell. they don't have viewDidLoad. @i

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I think your cell is not visible on screen that's why cellForRow is not calling have you checked with setting the background color to ShopMenuViewCell?

Comment: Have you also implemented the numberOfSections function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem for about 5 days and found a solution!

First Reference Site: Joel's Answer [cellForRowAtIndexPath: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called)

Second reference site: Paolo's answer
[Swift: UITableViewCell rowheight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478160/swift-uitableviewcell-rowheight)

When I add another kind of TableCell, the vertical size of the cell in question is small.

So I increased the size of the Cell's RowHeight (frame.height) before reloading the data and it's fixed!

Currently, cellforrowat runs safely. Your answers were helpful to the results.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
class ShopMenuViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!

    var menuPrice: MenuPrice!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
      super.awakeFromNib()
    }

   fun setUpTable() {
     self.menuTableView.regCells(cells: ["ShopMenuInformationCell"])
      self.menuTableView.delegate = self
      self.menuTableView.dataSource = self
      self.menuTableView.reloadData() 
     }
}
```

and call the function **setUpTable()** from **ShopMenuViewCell** as an **cell.setUpTable()**

Comment: I thought this was the answer, but it did not work. It's really sad.

Comment: can you please send regCells(cells: ["ShopMenuInformationCell"]) function.? @Enkha

Comment: I'm not able to find out in code. It will be inside the UITableViewExtension      regCells(cells: ["ShopMenuInformationCell"])

Comment: @Enkha Use this code inside cellForRow                                                                                                          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShopMenuViewCell") as? ShopMenuViewCell else {
                fatalError()
            }
            cell.backgroudColor  = .red
            return cell
        }

Comment: I added the code.
There is no meaning because cellForRowAt is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**Solution 1**

```
class ShopMenuViewCell: UITableViewCell {

       @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView! {
                didSet {
                    self.menuTableView.regCells(cells: ["ShopMenuInformationCell"])
                    self.menuTableView.delegate = self
                    self.menuTableView.dataSource = self
                }
            }
    }
```

---

**Solution 2:** Please check Anand Verma Answer

Comment: I`ll try. Thank you very much.